# Button is not taking the theme effect in jetpack compose

Tags: java, android, kotlin, button, android-jetpack-compose

I have a project in XML and I m trying to add a specific feature to it using Jetpack Compose. I have been using Compose Navigation. The problem is that the button color is Purple(maybe the default color) and my UI Theme color is Green. How to make the button take the effect of the theme color?

Comment: If you disable dynamicColor in the  Theme.kt does it change?

Comment: Is the Composable wrapped within the Theme? Provide a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: make sure you have theme configured correctly, disabled the dynamic color and last you are wrapping your composable with your theme. If all these 3 things are done, then you'll get the desired result.